# Laravel: show data in laravel with two table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-query-builder

I want to display data in laravel.
This is the classrooms table:

[image: table]

This is the students table:

[image: table]

this is the classroom_student table :

[image: table]

I expect a result like this:

[image: this]

With **class** from the classroom table, **year** from the student table (the year the student was created), and **data** from the student table (data for each month, sample data:[2,4,6] means Jan: 2, Feb: 4, Mar: 6). I don't know how to make it. Can you help me? thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup a many to many relationship both of your models (classroom model and student model. It will look something like this:

```
class Classroom extends Model {

  public function students(){
     return $this->hasMany(Student:class, 'student_id');
  }

}

class Student extends Model {

  public function classrooms(){
     return $this->hasMany(Classroom:class, 'classroom_id');
  }

}
```

Here is also a reference to laravel docs for the exact solution:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Answer (score 0):

You Should use HasMany Relation in both Models and while fetching data call this relation function to get data related to other model and set expected title for those data in Transformer.